Array + Curve modifiers, objects won't follow a curve
I want to duplicate a segment along the Bezier curve. It should look like this in a final result

Any prior transformation was applied, transform set to pivot point, everything is positioned on 0.
And this is the problem. I tried different settings for Array modifier, Fixed Count, Constant Offset with same result. It just won't follow the curve.



Have you applied the rotation of the object? Please share the filr

I did rotated both segment and the circle. Then object>apply rotation.

Here is the file, is wetransfer ok? https://we.tl/t-XPxBcthoJk

The origin is at the same location as the curve's origin, it's ok, but the mesh is far away from its origin, so right click > Set Origin > Geometry to Origin:

Also the array is on Z so choose Deform Axis -Z:


Thanks! It solved the problem.
